# Store Permissions for Apache Shiro

Tags: java, jsp, shiro

I'm starting with the framework Apache Shiro, I felt great and very flexible. Within an application we want to control permissions for certain parts of the web with jsp tags for "**shiro: hasPermission**".

Shiro I understand that things like this can tell **Module4:action1**, but for more complex scenarios as ***module1-> module1.1-> action3*** not think of a structure to store this in the database.

[image]

Depending on the model of our application suggestion What I do to store the permissions on the database, What tables could use?.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shiro's default [WildcardPermission syntax](http://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html) can handle arbitrary numbers of `:` delimited tokens.  You could get by on something as easy as defining your permissions as follows:

```
module1:module1.1:action3
```

etc.

This means you only need an association table, e.g. `account_permissions` that has an `account_id` and a `permission` string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Les. One more question, if I indicate in the Permit `module1:*` I then indicating that you have permissions on everything that follows from `module1`?